# Phase-space average equal to the quantum mechanical average in the early universe

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cosmology, statistical-mechanics

I was reading  Mukhanov's book of cosmology [http://www.amazon.com/Physical-Foundations-Cosmology-Viatcheslav-Mukhanov/dp/0521563984](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521563984) , specifically about symmetry restoration in the early universe where he is calculating the *vacuum* and *thermal* contributions to the effective potential of a hypothetical scalar fied  and, at the end of page 167 he does the following affirmation:

*In a homogeneous and isotropic universe the spatial average can be replaced by the quantum average.*

As far as I know from quantum statistical mechanics, the unique way to make sense to this affirmation is to consider

1. the spatial average as the phase-space average and
2. that the state (vector) of the system is precisely known, meaning that this state is a pure state.

I suspect that this is indeed the case since but I am not sure about it. Can anyone explain this?